# Proof: If $ϕ: R \to R'$ is a ring isomorphism, then its inverse $ϕ^{-1} : R' \to R$ is a ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

**Proposition.** If $ϕ: R \to R'$ is a ring isomorphism, then its inverse $ϕ^{-1} : R' \to R$ is a ring homomorphism.

How would you start a proof for this proposition?

Comment: For me, a foobar isomorphism between two foobars $A$ and $B$ is **per definition** a foobar homomorphism $\phi\colon A\to B$  such that there exists a foobar homomorphism $\psi\colon B\to A$ such that $ \psi\circ\phi$ and $\phi\circ\psi$ are the respective identities. - Then there is nothing to be shown

Answer (score 0):

Since $\phi$ is a bijective function, proving that $a=\phi^{-1}(b)$ is the same thing as proving that $\phi(a)=b$. Therefore if you want to prove, for instance, that $\phi^{-1}(a-b)=\phi^{-1}(a)-\phi^{-1}(b)$ for all $a$, $b$, then you only need to prove that $\phi(\phi^{-1}(a-b))=\phi(\phi^{-1}(a)-\phi^{-1}(b))$ for all $a$, $b$.

Answer (score 0):

$x,y \in R', \phi^{-1}(x)\phi^{-1}(y)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(u))\phi^{-1}(\phi(v))=uv$ for some $u,v\in R$

$\phi^{-1}(x)+\phi^{-1}(y)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(u))+\phi^{-1}(\phi(v))=u+v$ for some $u,v\in R$

$R\cong R', \phi(1)=1, \phi^{-1}(1)=1$

Hence proven.